# No errors, sql is right, table doesn't update

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to update my database via a simple form and for some reason, the table doesn't update. I tried the sql query inside phpmyadmin and it seemed to work fine.

```
     <?php 
include("_/inc/session_handler.php");
include("_/inc/dbcon.php");
$uplform = "";

if(isset($_POST['insert'])){
    $post=$_POST['wish'];
    $succes="";
    $succes .="<h1>SUCCES</h1>";
    $insert_wish_sql="INSERT INTO wishlist(wish_id, wish, datetime)VALUES (null, '$post', CURDATE())";//insert new post
    echo $succes;
}



//The form

$uplform .="<form action=\"\"method=\"post\">";
$uplform .="<input type='text' name='wish' placeholder='wish'/>";
$uplform .="<input type=\"submit\" name=\"insert\" value=\"Upload\" />";
$uplform .="</form>";

?>
```

i even get the succes message, but nothing happens in the table. what am i missing?

UPDATE:
I just went fully retarded. i forgot to add

```
$link = mysql_connect($host, $login, $pw);
    mysql_select_db($database);
```

so i was basically not connected to the database 8-|. 
Thanx a lot!

Comment: you are having an insert query and you are saying you are updating ?

Comment: There are so much to correct, that I'm not shure where to begin. Get yourself a book and learn.

Comment: You only assign query to variable and do not execute it.

Comment: Where you executiong your query

Comment: Hmm, php is not going to guess that in your string you have query that you want to run. Use [`PDO`](http://php.net/pdo) or [`mysqli`](http://php.net/mysqli) to interact with databases. Also read more about [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Whats in _/inc/dbcon.php we can't tell you how to fix this without knowing what functions you are using to talk to your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I miss your connection to a database server ( I guess its' that include) and finally if a connection exits, you need to send/execute your query.

The API's: PDO or mysqli is good for it.

or to test stuff, with the mysql API ( but I would not recommend it to use it live)
https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php

Answer (score 0):

There may be one problem looking at your code is that it is not executed. SO execute it like this

```
 $res = mysqli_query($conn, $insert_wish_sql);
```

But the bigger concern is your sql itself as you are passing null as the value for id. Is your id is not primary or auto increment. If it is then it will fail always.

Comment: how did you find out the OP is using `mysql_` extension!

Comment: well, i tried to pass empty instead of null, and it didn't seem to work either. anyway, i have tried your suggestion as well, added the $res and still doesnt do much. i assume that i need to run the $res as well? (i wouldn't say php is my thing..)

Comment: @ParaschivIonut which extension are you using? like [mysql_](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)